# VBA Sheet protection with UserInterFaceOnly:=True not allowing copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have a macro which copies cells from the source sheet onto the current sheet.

I have protected all sheets with the below in order to allow vba to still run:

```
Sub ProtectAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
       ws.Protect , UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next ws
End Sub
```

The macro to copy/paste has always worked in any scenario, but now that I am protecting with the above code it only works if pasting to the same source sheet.

If pasting on a different sheet I get a runtime error that states it is read only.

All Sheets including the source are protected in the above manner.

The runtime error points to this line of code in the macro:

```
copySheet.Range("2:" & copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Rows(LRow)
```

```
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
    
    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Template")
    Set pasteSheet = ActiveSheet
    With pasteSheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0 Then
            copySheet.Rows(1).Copy .Rows(1)
            LRow = 2
        Else
            LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
        
        copySheet.Range("2:" & copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Rows(LRow)
              
    End With
End Sub
```

What could be happening here and how could I rectify?

Comment: which error do you get? Do you run `ProtectAllSheets` in the workbook_open event? Because `UserInterFaceOnly:=True` gets lost on closing the workbook. And needs to be re-applied again on opening the workbook.

Comment: Yes in workbook_open. I get run-time error 1004: the cell or chart you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only...

Comment: Well can you tell what is `.Rows(LRow)` refering to? Can you show a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: Have edited above to include the full code.

Comment: you `Set pasteSheet = ActiveSheet` in which workbook is the `ActiveSheet` in the same as `Worksheets("Template")`? If it is in the workbook the code is written in I recommmend to specify that `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` and `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")`. Just to make sure it is reliable. Can you confirm that everything is in the same workbook?

Comment: Yes they are in the same workbook and I have now updated that, thanks. Still receiving the error.

Comment: That's strange because then it should work. What happens if you call `ProtectAllSheets` before calling the copy procedure?

Comment: I have ProtectAllSheets in the workbook_open event but also as a macro button in the event that I need to unprotect. I have tried the copy procedure both directly after opening the workbook and after unprotecting and reprotecting with the macro. Either way I can only successfully call the copy procedure on the "Template" sheet. If I unprotect, I can call it on any sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I tried splitting the copy and paste statement into 2 separate statements rather than 1 to see if it would work, and it does.

Therefore the issue, when a sheet is protected with UserInterFaceOnly:=true, is copying **directly** between worksheets. However there is no issue in first copying to the clipboard and then pasting to a different sheet.

The code works as follows, as 2 statements:

```
copySheet.Range("2:" & copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy 
.Rows(LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```